# How can I select the keyframes on only the highlighted channel?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I'm currently working through a tutorial, and I've come across something that's a bit unclear to me. In the tutorial video, the instructor was able to use box selection in the graph editor while limiting the selection to the highlighted channel. It seemed like they had locked the other channels, but upon closer inspection, that doesn't appear to be the case. I attempted to reach out to them for clarification, but unfortunately, I haven't received a response.

Does anyone have any insights on how to achieve this? Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: A link to the tutorial and the time in it where the selection occurred would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnEason Generally I would agree, but here it is not necessary, that's a simple option in the preferences... (see answer)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I'm surprised it isn't available directly in the Graph Editor View menu.

Comment: @JohnEason Yeah... There is something confusingly similar sounding though in the _Graph Editor_,in the _View_ menu you find "Only Selected Keyframes Handles", but this is just a visual thing probably to not obstruct the view with dozens of unused handles - but it does not change the ability to select the keyframes and/or handles.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yes. I saw that! :^(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Blender Preferences* under *Animation* > *F-Curves*, enable the option *Only Show Selected F-Curve Keyframes*.

[image: selected f-curve keyframes]

Comment: wow that's the kind of option that should be available in the Graph Editor itself

Comment: @moonboots Yes, I don't understand why it's not. Or if it is, where it is hidden.